# What is the etymology/origin of the adjoint symbol $\dashv\,$?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

For categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, a pair of functors $\mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{\;R\;} \mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{C} \xleftarrow{\;L\;} \mathcal{D}\,$ are an *adjoint* pair if for any objects $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal{D}$ we have a bijection $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(LY,X) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(Y,RX).$ This adjoint relationship between $L$ and $R$ is often indicated by writing:

## $$L \dashv R$$

Why do we use the symbol $\dashv\,$? Who originally used $\dashv$ in this context? I imagine that someone has asked this question before somewhere, right? But I couldn't find it here on MathSE or elsewhere.

Comment: I have no idea, but here's a guess: the word *adjoint* is cognate with *adjunct* (cf. *adjunction*), which in regular usage means something attached to something else. The symbols $\top$, $\vdash$, $\bot$ and $\dashv$ look like something attached to something else, but the symbols $\top$, $\vdash$ and $\bot$ already mean other things, so $\dashv$ is the natural choice ;)

Comment: I don't really know about *why*, but apparently *who* is Daniel Kan : the symbol is introduced immediately after the definition in this paper http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1958-087-02/S0002-9947-1958-0131451-0/S0002-9947-1958-0131451-0.pdf

Comment: @ArnaudD. Do you think this is the first usage of the symbol in this context? (as opposed to the [linear-algebra-flavored context](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Adjoint.html))

Comment: Well, if by "this context" you mean "between adjoint functors", then yes, since it's also the first usage of adjoint functors.